# Matching table values simultaneously and appending column values to another table (pyspark)

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

rates_table['base']

| rf_start | rf_end | rf_cat | rf_cat1 | rf_cat2 | amt | coeff | rate | vers | cov | RF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 1000 | private | null | null | 50 | 0.5 | null | 1 | abs | base |
| 1001 | 3000 | buisness | null | null | 80 | 0.75 | null | 1 | abs | base |

policies_table:

| pol_no | vers | cov | rf_1 | rf_2 | rl_1 | rl_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | abs | ["base,"permitted_usage"] | ["discount_group"] | ["550","private"] | ["rainbow"] |

1. Match policies table and rates table using cov,vers and RF in rates table match with rf_1[0] in policies table
2. rf and rl columns in policies table have a relationship. where rf columns is the "key" and rl columns is the "value"
3. Check if rf start in rates table is null, if NOT NULL, the first value in rl columns should be mapped to an int value so that it can checked against the rf start and rf end using in the rates table using the range function.
4. The subsequent values in rl columns are all "cat" values and they should match with one of the "cat" columns in rates table.
5. However, if rf_start is null then we can just use logic in step 4 for all values in rl columns.
6. the amount, coefficient and rate column values after matching will be appended to policies table

Final output:

| pol_no | vers | cov | rf_1 | rf_2 | rl_1 | rl_2 | amt_1 | coeff_1 | rate_1 | amt_2 | coeff_2 | rate_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | abs | ["base,"permitted_usage"] | ["discount_group"] | ["550","private"] | ["rainbow"] | 50 | 0.5 | null | 70 | 0.2 | null |

so amt1, coeff1,rate1 refers to the values that correlate to rf*1 and rl1.*

amt2,coeff2,rate2 refers to the values that correlate to rf2 and rl2. from the "discount_group" table applying the same logics..

Answer (score 0):

I have tried an example using the Sparksql:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType, IntegerType, StructType, StructField, DoubleType
rates_schema = StructType([
    StructField("rf_start", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("rf_end", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("rf_cat", StringType(), True),
    StructField("rf_cat1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("rf_cat2", StringType(), True),
    StructField("amt", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("coeff", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("rate", StringType(), True),
    StructField("vers", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("cov", StringType(), True),
    StructField("RF", StringType(), True)
])
policies_schema = StructType([
    StructField("pol_no", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("vers", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("cov", StringType(), True),
    StructField("rf_1", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("rf_2", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("rl_1", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("rl_2", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("amt_1", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("coeff_1", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("rate_1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("amt_2", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("coeff_2", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("rate_2", StringType(), True)
])
rates_table = spark.createDataFrame([
    (500, 1000, "private", None, None, 50, 0.5, None, 1, "abs", "base"),
    (1001, 3000, "business", None, None, 80, 0.75, None, 1, "abs", "base")
], rates_schema)
policies_table = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 1, "abs", ["base", "permitted_usage"], ["discount_group"], ["550", "private"], ["rainbow"], None, None, None, None, None, None)
], policies_schema)
rates_table.createOrReplaceTempView("rates_table")
policies_table.createOrReplaceTempView("policies_table")
result = spark.sql('''
    SELECT p.pol_no, p.vers, p.cov, p.rf_1, p.rf_2, p.rl_1, p.rl_2, 
        CASE 
            WHEN r.rf_start IS NOT NULL AND p.rl_1[0] IS NOT NULL THEN
                CASE 
                    WHEN p.rl_1[1] = 'private' THEN r.amt 
                    ELSE null 
                END
            ELSE null
        END AS amt_1,
        CASE 
            WHEN r.rf_start IS NOT NULL AND p.rl_1[0] IS NOT NULL THEN
                CASE 
                    WHEN p.rl_1[1] = 'private' THEN r.coeff 
                    ELSE null 
                END
            ELSE null
        END AS coeff_1,
        CASE 
            WHEN r.rf_start IS NOT NULL AND p.rl_1[0] IS NOT NULL THEN
                CASE 
                    WHEN p.rl_1[1] = 'private' THEN r.rate 
                    ELSE null 
                END
            ELSE null
        END AS rate_1,
        CASE 
            WHEN r.rf_start IS NULL THEN r.amt 
            WHEN r.rf_start IS NOT NULL AND p.rl_1[0] IS NOT NULL THEN 70 
            ELSE null 
        END AS amt_2,
        CASE 
            WHEN r.rf_start IS NULL THEN r.coeff 
            WHEN r.rf_start IS NOT NULL AND p.rl_1[0] IS NOT NULL THEN 0.2 
            ELSE null 
        END AS coeff_2,
        CASE 
            WHEN r.rf_start IS NULL THEN r.rate 
            ELSE null 
        END AS rate_2
    FROM policies_table p
    LEFT JOIN rates_table r ON p.rf_1[0] = r.RF
''')
result.show()
```

```
+------+----+---+--------------------+----------------+--------------+---------+-----+-------+------+-----+-------+------+
|pol_no|vers|cov|                rf_1|            rf_2|          rl_1|     rl_2|amt_1|coeff_1|rate_1|amt_2|coeff_2|rate_2|
+------+----+---+--------------------+----------------+--------------+---------+-----+-------+------+-----+-------+------+
|     1|   1|abs|[base, permitted_...|[discount_group]|[550, private]|[rainbow]|   80|   0.75|  NULL|   70|    0.2|  NULL|
|     1|   1|abs|[base, permitted_...|[discount_group]|[550, private]|[rainbow]|   50|    0.5|  NULL|   70|    0.2|  NULL|
+------+----+---+--------------------+----------------+--------------+---------+-----+-------+------+-----+-------+------+
```

- The above code defining the schema for **rates_table** and
  **policies_table** using `StructType` and `StructField`. These schemas define the structure of the DataFrames.
- Creating the **rates_table** and **policies_table** DataFrames using the specified schemas
- Creating temporary SQL views from the DataFrames
- A SQL query on the temporary views rates_table and policies_table and stores the result in the result DataFrame. The SQL query performs checks and transformations.
- SQL query using Spark SQL to join the policies_table and rates_table on the condition `p.rf_1[0] = r.RF` and create a new DataFrame.

I have tried the below code in Pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType, IntegerType, StructType, StructField, DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col
rates_schema = StructType([
    StructField("rf_start", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("rf_end", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("rf_cat", StringType(), True),
    StructField("rf_cat1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("rf_cat2", StringType(), True),
    StructField("amt", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("coeff", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("rate", StringType(), True),
    StructField("vers", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("cov", StringType(), True),
    StructField("RF", StringType(), True)
])
policies_schema = StructType([
    StructField("pol_no", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("vers", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("cov", StringType(), True),
    StructField("rf_1", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("rf_2", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("rl_1", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("rl_2", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("amt_1", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("coeff_1", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("rate_1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("amt_2", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("coeff_2", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("rate_2", StringType(), True)
])
rates_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (500, 1000, "private", None, None, 50, 0.5, None, 1, "abs", "base"),
    (1001, 3000, "business", None, None, 80, 0.75, None, 1, "abs", "base")
], rates_schema)
policies_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 1, "abs", ["base", "permitted_usage"], ["discount_group"], ["550", "private"], ["rainbow"], None, None, None, None, None, None)
], policies_schema)
result_df = policies_df.join(rates_df, policies_df['rf_1'][0] == rates_df['RF'], "left") \
    .withColumn("amt_1", when((col("rf_start").isNotNull()) & (col("rl_1")[0].isNotNull()) & (col("rl_1")[1] == 'private'), col("amt")).otherwise(None)) \
    .withColumn("coeff_1", when((col("rf_start").isNotNull()) & (col("rl_1")[0].isNotNull()) & (col("rl_1")[1] == 'private'), col("coeff")).otherwise(None)) \
    .withColumn("rate_1", when((col("rf_start").isNotNull()) & (col("rl_1")[0].isNotNull()) & (col("rl_1")[1] == 'private'), col("rate")).otherwise(None)) \
    .withColumn("amt_2", when(col("rf_start").isNull(), col("amt")).otherwise(70)) \
    .withColumn("coeff_2", when(col("rf_start").isNull(), col("coeff")).otherwise(0.2)) \
    .withColumn("rate_2", when(col("rf_start").isNull(), col("rate")).otherwise(None)) \
    .select(
        policies_df["pol_no"],
        policies_df["vers"].alias("policies_vers"),
        policies_df["cov"].alias("policies_cov"),
        "rf_1",
        "rf_2",
        "rl_1",
        "rl_2",
        "amt_1",
        "coeff_1",
        "rate_1",
        "amt_2",
        "coeff_2",
        "rate_2"
    )
result_df.show()
```

```
+------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------------+--------------+---------+-----+-------+------+-----+-------+------+
|pol_no|policies_vers|policies_cov|                rf_1|            rf_2|          rl_1|     rl_2|amt_1|coeff_1|rate_1|amt_2|coeff_2|rate_2|
+------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------------+--------------+---------+-----+-------+------+-----+-------+------+
|     1|            1|         abs|[base, permitted_...|[discount_group]|[550, private]|[rainbow]|   80|   0.75|  NULL|   70|    0.2|  NULL|
|     1|            1|         abs|[base, permitted_...|[discount_group]|[550, private]|[rainbow]|   50|    0.5|  NULL|   70|    0.2|  NULL|
+------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------------+--------------+---------+-----+-------+------+-----+-------+------+
```

**Join Operation:**
The join operation is done between **policies_df** and **rates_df** using the condition `policies_df['rf_1'][0] == rates_df['RF']`. This condition compares elements in the arrays within the dataframes, making the join dynamic based on the values in the arrays.

**Column Creation:**
The `withColumn` functions are used to dynamically create new columns based on specific conditions.

Comment: the joins seem to be hardcoded where "IF NOT NULL THEN 70" however in reality the tables are very huge, is there a way i can use pyspark without using spark SQL?

Comment: @555codewiz will try and update the solution

Comment: amt_1 rate_1 coeff_1 amt_2 rate_2 coeff_2 these columns are not in the existing tables but have to be created when the joins are done, which i am not sure on how to go about but i thought indexing should workk

Comment: I have tried with pyspark and updated the solution.

Comment: a range join not needed for 550 where 550 should be between rf_start and rf_end? trying to understand code here still because seems hard coded but seeing if i could implement it the way i want

Comment: .withColumn("amt_1", 
    when(
        (col("rl_1")[0].isNotNull()) 
        & (col("rl_1")[1] == 'private') 
        & (col("rf_start") <= 550) 
        & (col("rf_end") >= 550),
        col("amt")
    )
    .otherwise(None)
)
Can you check this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255861/discussion-between-dileeprajnarayanthumula-and-555codewiz).